# Crawling two-level website, need comments in new rows

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am very new to web scraping , and I am trying to scrape this online forum: https://community.whattoexpect.com/forums/postpartum-depression.html

It is a two-level site where the main page is a list of discussion posts, and you can click on each post to get the full content and see the reply comments. The main site also has pagination.

I want my final CSV to look something like this:

[image]

The idea is to have the main post in one row, and then the replies in the next rows. I will be using the same ID for main post and replies, so that they can be linked.

Here is my Scrapy spider so far:

```py
import scrapy
import datetime

class PeripartumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'peripartum'

    start_urls = ['http://www.community.whattoexpect.com/forums/postpartum-depression.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for post_link in response.xpath('//*[@id="group-discussions"]/div[3]/div/div/a/@href').extract():
            link = response.urljoin(post_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_thread)

        # Checks if the main page has a link to next page if True keep parsing.
        next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="page-link"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

        # Going into each post and extracting information.

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        original_post = response.xpath("//*[@class='__messageContent fr-element fr-view']/p/text()").extract()
        title = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__title']/text()").extract_first()
        author_name = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__name']/text()").extract_first()
        unixtime = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__updated']/@data-date").extract_first()
        unixtime = int(unixtime) / 1000  # Removing milliseconds
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unixtime).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
        replies_list = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-replies__list']").getall()

        # Getting the comments and their information for each post

        reply_post = response.xpath(".//*[@class='wte-reply__content__message __messageContent fr-element fr-view']/p/text()").extract()
        reply_author = response.xpath("//*[@class='wte-reply__author__name']/text()").extract()
        reply_time = response.xpath("//*[@class='wte-reply__author__updated']/@data-date").extract()
        for reply in reply_time:
            reply_date = int(reply_time) / 1000  # Removing milliseconds
            reply_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(reply_date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

        yield {
            "title": title,
            "author_name": author_name,
            "time": timestamp,
            "post": original_post,
            "reply_author": reply_author,
            "reply_timestamp": reply_timestamp,
            "replies": reply_post
        }
```

When I try to run my spider, I am getting 0 crawls. I am not sure if I am correctly following the links to each post. And, should I use something like Python's CSV library to get the comments to load into the next row but with the original post ID?

Comment: How are you running your spider? Also, have you tried to pick those elements out manually using `scrapy shell www.example.com`? That's how I was able to make sure I'd selected the correct elements. [Here are the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) for Scrapy Shell.

Comment: Hi, Yes I've tested my xpaths with Scrapy shell, and I've seen that they are returning the right values. I am running my spider through a Miniconda environment.

Comment: Ok, how did you set up the scrapy environment? For example did you follow the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and use `startproject`?

Comment: Yes, I used startproject, just like the Example in the docs. I don't think I'm having any issue with that part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care about

- the existing web page document structure
- and your code structure parsing the content

May there is a better coding than the following, just identifying `n` comments and after that looping over the comments. In this case you don't need to `zip` the lists together. But you could use it as a starting point

```
import scrapy
import datetime

class PeripartumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'peripartum'

    start_urls = ['https://community.whattoexpect.com/forums/postpartum-depression.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for post_link in response.xpath('//*[@id="group-discussions"]/div[3]/div/div/a/@href').extract():
            link = response.urljoin(post_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_thread)

        # Checks if the main page has a link to next page if True keep parsing.
        next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="page-link"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

        # Going into each post and extracting information.

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        original_post = response.xpath("//*[@class='__messageContent fr-element fr-view']/p/text()").extract()
        title = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__title']/text()").extract_first()
        author_name = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__name']/text()").extract_first()
        unixtime = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-original-post__author__updated']/@data-date").extract_first()
        unixtime = int(unixtime) / 1000  # Removing milliseconds
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unixtime).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
        replies_list = response.xpath("//*[@class='discussion-replies__list']").getall()

        # Getting the comments and their information for each post
        replies_post = response.xpath(".//*[@class='wte-reply__content__message __messageContent fr-element fr-view']/p/text()").extract()
        replies_author = response.xpath("//*[@class='wte-reply__author__name']/text()").extract()
        replies_time = response.xpath("//*[@class='wte-reply__author__updated']/@data-date").extract()
        replies = zip(replies_post, replies_author, replies_time)

        for reply_post, reply_author, reply_time in replies:
            reply_date = int(reply_time) / 1000  # Removing milliseconds
            reply_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(reply_date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
            yield {
                "title": title,
                "author_name": author_name,
                "time": timestamp,
                "post": original_post,
                "reply_author": reply_author,
                "reply_timestamp": reply_timestamp,
                "replies": reply_post
            }
```

You may also have to take care about pagination in comments.